# Is there a way to change table into multiple dimension array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I make a table with row and column attribute, here is the code:

```
<table border='2px' cellpadding='20px'>
  <tr id='rowZero'>
      <td id='zeroZero'>-</td>
      <td id='zeroOne'>-</td>
      <td id='zeroTwo'>-</td>
      <td id='zeroThree'>-</td>
      <td id='zeroFour'>-</td>``
  </tr>
  <tr id='rowOne'> 
      <td id='oneZero'>-</td>
      <td id='oneOne'>-</td>
      <td id='oneTwo'>-</td>
      <td id='oneThree'>-</td>
      <td id='oneFour'>-</td>
  </tr>
```

But i have no idea how to convert it into a multiple dimension array.

I want to access the 'innerText' of my table with this pattern :

```
td id='zeroZero' on array index [0,0]
td id='zeroOne' on array index [0,1]
td id='zeroTwo' on array index [0,2]
td id='zeroThree' on array index [0,3]
td id='zeroFour' on array index [0,4]

td id='oneZero' on array index [1,0]
td id='oneOne' on array index [1,1]
td id='oneTwo' on array index [1,2]
td id='oneThree' on array index [1,3]
td id='oneFour' on array index [1,4]
```

Can anyone give me codes to convert the table into array with this pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function tableToArray(table) {
  return [...table.querySelectorAll('tr')].map(row => {
    return [...row.querySelectorAll('td')].map(cell => cell.textContent)
  })
}
```

And you can use it passing your table as an argument

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table')
const array = tableToArray(table)
```